# How to get Oculus Rift DK2 working in Unity 5.4 on windows 10

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, virtual-reality, oculus-runtime

I upgraded to Windows 10, downloaded the newest drivers for the graphics card, and installed the [latest SDK](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/pc/1.3.2/Oculus_SDK_for_Windows/) I also installed the [oculus utilities for unity](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/game-engines/1.3.2/Oculus_Utilities_for_Unity_5/) 5 and the [ovr plugin](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/game-engines/1.3.2/OVRPlugin_for_Unity_5/). I tried following [this tutorial](http://talesfromtherift.com/getting-started-with-unity-and-oculus-rift-sdk-0-4-0/) but I cant seem to find the OculusConfigTool referenced. Also I've been trying to use the [VRSamples](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/51519) from unity but I keep getting [VRDevice] initialization of device oculus not found.

I had this working before i upgraded to windows 10, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Upgrading to win10 was the actual mistake. Patchwork, lousy OS, a weak, pimped up Vista. In other words, "if it works, don't fix it". Anyway! Does your Oculus work as intended? Did you try to use it under win10 outside Unity?

Comment: works outside of unity ... I'm trying to get the new Kinect working with it as well, which requires windows 10 ( only reason I upgraded ) ... now that is working but it broke the oculus functionality

Comment: Unity + Oculus works flawlessly with Windows10.  Everyone who works with Oculus has changed to W10.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally got this to work ... in the instructions I followed it said to place the ovr plugin files in a folder called "unity". I found thisthis thread http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-3-vrdevice-initialization-of-device-oculus-failed.372663/ and placed it in a folder called "oculus" and replaced the file in there, now it works

Comment: hahh. funny. mark your answer as the solution then. let it lay here for future win10 upgraders :)